# Add Full Screen Video foreground while window is loading

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I need help implementing a web page that plays a video in the foreground (13 seconds full) while the webpage loads in the background.

Ideally I would like to play the video via youtube or another hosted URL since we have bandwidth limitations but self hosting can work too if there is no alternative.

I could do

```
<video autoplay loop muted poster="screenshot.jpg" id="background">
<source src="/sample-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and hide it `on load` but if you have a more elegant solution, I could really use some help.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm concerned about using a video as a design decision. Is a 13 second video really going to load faster than the web page? How big is the web page that loading it is slower than loading a video?

Comment: Hi @master565 the page is fairly optimised and only 2.6 MB with 50 requests. Think of it this way, we want the video to load and play for 13 seconds and once the video is done buffering, the page can load into the browser cache. Once the 13 seconds are up, the content fades into the video. (Or just the video hides away and the content is there in a flash) 

What are your general thoughts on using this approach? -Thanks

Comment: 13 seconds seems like an eternity for a page to load. I'd build it to scaffold the basic content as fast as possible, then follow-up with the video once the page was loaded.

Comment: @TimHayes Thats a great suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin such as [bigvideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) or [Vide](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/) to easily add and manage a full screen video background, render your site content underneath, and fade out the video once your site has loaded + the video is complete. Just make sure to check out the docs for each plugin to see if there are video events you can hook into to achieve the effect you are looking for.

As far as page load and setup, I do agree with the concerns voiced above; it is totally possible to fire up the video as soon as the script and element is available. If that's the case, you'll want to make sure your video is as light as can be. Use a small preloader or other load notification, load the video element + script and begin playing as early as possible, then queue up other scripts and dom after that.

Comment: Thanks @DabaloSe7eN